# Rails: How to display values from pg db with jQuery in select

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

I'm working at my app and I have two tables: users and departments. What I want to do is to get ID of department that is chosen in select box in my form (I've already done it) and make a query to Postgres db which will select users that belong to chosen department by department's ID (I have foreign key in users table which contains info about users department). Selected users should be displayed in another select box, so it can be easily choosen by real user.

My question is, how can I make it work in Javascript/jQuery? This is part of code (I know it's unnecessary):

code.js (there is only getting value from select box as I said):

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
 var value = $( "#departmentselect, option:selected" ).val();
});
```

index.html.erb:

```
    <%= f.collection_select :dzial_id, Dzial.all, :id, :nazwa, prompt: "Wybierz", id:"departmentselect"%>
```

That's all. I would be thankful if anyone would show how to deal with it.

EDIT:

Here is zgloszenies_controller.rb.

```
class ZgloszeniesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_zgloszeny, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :print]

  # GET /zgloszenies
  # GET /zgloszenies.json
  def index
    @zgloszenies = Zgloszenie.where("nazwa_urzadzenia ILIKE ?", "%#{params[:search]}%")
  end

  # GET /zgloszenies/1
  # GET /zgloszenies/1.json
  def show
  end

  def print
    @zgloszenie = Zgloszenie.find(params[:id])
  end

  # GET /zgloszenies/new
  def new
    @zgloszeny = Zgloszenie.new
  end

  # GET /zgloszenies/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /zgloszenies
  # POST /zgloszenies.json
  def create
    @zgloszeny = Zgloszenie.new(zgloszeny_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @zgloszeny.save
        format.html { redirect_to @zgloszeny, notice: 'Zgloszenie was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @zgloszeny }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @zgloszeny.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /zgloszenies/1
  # PATCH/PUT /zgloszenies/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @zgloszeny.update(zgloszeny_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @zgloszeny, notice: 'Zgloszenie was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @zgloszeny }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @zgloszeny.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /zgloszenies/1
  # DELETE /zgloszenies/1.json
  def destroy
    @zgloszeny.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to zgloszenies_url, notice: 'Zgloszenie was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_zgloszeny
      @zgloszeny = Zgloszenie.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def zgloszeny_params
      params.require(:zgloszenie).permit(:dzial_id, :data_zgloszenia, :opis_uszkodzenia, :nazwa_urzadzenia, :user_id, :wysylka, :priorytet, :status, :data_naprawy, :pracownikid)
    end
end
```

The main idea is to let user choose department he want to send informations and he will get in the second select box list of users that works in chosen department

Comment: Please post your controller code that will be returning the response based on `value`.

Comment: I've added it by editing post ;)